# How can I migrate this from IntelliJ to Android Studio

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-studio

I have a project that contains multiple modules, including android libraries and one android application, each has a build.gradle file, how do I integrate all of these gradle files in the project so that everything is compiled.

Answer (score 0):

In general you set up a settings.gradle file at the root directory under which all the modules lie (see http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html) for information on the format of the settings.gradle file. Then you import the project into Android Studio and point it at settings.gradle when it asks for a file to import.